# Connect to shared folder with php

Tags: php

It's possible to connect to a shared folder and list, read or write files in the folder as if it were a local folder with `php`? I was searching but I haven't found anything that woks for me.

Comment: Only if the folder is on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to access Windows-based Share with SMB protocol, use can use [Icewind\SMD library](https://github.com/icewind1991/SMB).

Answer (score 0):

It can't possible with only PHP, We can't access the local directory/file using PHP.
But, If you write some Thread or File Watcher task using Java(Watch service) or Python or any other supported technology and send file related events to your PHP web-service or API.
Not sure but if will think in that way...it can be possible.